# Assign any type to a variable

Tags: java

I have two objects from different types:

```
ObservableListView listView;
ObservableGridView gridView;
```

Is it possible to make a variable that will assign one of the objects based on some condition. And after that to call their methods? Is it something with Generic Types? Sorry if it has been asked, I don't know how is called this technique.

**Edit:** I'm trying to avoid code duplication:

```
if (phone) {
        listView = (ObservableListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.castdetailscredits);
        if (listView != null) {
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            listView.setScrollViewCallbacks(activity.getCastDetailsFragment());
            listView.setTouchInterceptionViewGroup((ViewGroup) activity.getCastDetailsFragment().getView().findViewById(R.id.containerLayout));
            Bundle save = activity.getCastDetailsCreditsBundle();
            if (save != null) {
                moviesList = save.getParcelableArrayList("moviesList");
                movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row, this.moviesList);
                listView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
            }

        }
    } else {
        gridView = (ObservableGridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.castdetailscredits);
        if (gridView != null) {
            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            gridView.setScrollViewCallbacks(activity.getCastDetailsFragment());
            gridView.setTouchInterceptionViewGroup((ViewGroup) activity.getCastDetailsFragment().getView().findViewById(R.id.containerLayout));
            Bundle save = activity.getCastDetailsCreditsBundle();
            if (save != null) {
                moviesList = save.getParcelableArrayList("moviesList");
                movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row, this.moviesList);
                gridView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Add a common base interface or class and use that.

Comment: Can you share a more complete snippet so we get a clue of what you're trying to do?

Comment: do they have the same methods ?

Comment: Do you use this library: https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/tree/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/ksoichiro/android/observablescrollview? If  yes, then you can link that to the question. It helps to determine similarities between both classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to do this actually:

**Reflection**:

```
//I don't know this object so I'm using a default constructor
ObservableListView listView = new ObservableListView(); 
ObservableGridView gridView = new ObservableGridView();

Object obj;

if(condition)
{
    obj = listView;
}
else
{
    obj = gridView;
}

Method method = obj.getClass().getMethod("methodname", param1.getClass(), param2.getClass());
try
{
    method.invoke(obj, param1, param2);
}catch(Exception e){}
```

**Inheritance**:

```
//assuming that there is some parent class of both classes that contains methods that you would like to use
ObservableListView listView = new ObservableListView(); 
ObservableGridView gridView = new ObservableGridView();

ObservableView view;

if(condition)
{
    view = listView;
}
else
{
    view = gridView;
}

view.someMethod();
```

**Interface**:

```
//this assumes that both ObservableListView and ObservableGridView implement some interface 'IObservableView'
ObservableListView listView = new ObservableListView(); 
ObservableGridView gridView = new ObservableGridView();

IObservableView view;

if(condition)
{
    view = listView;
}
else
{
    view = gridView;
}

view.someMethod();
```

**Instanceof**:

```
//very flexible version. I think that this is the route I would choose
ObservableListView listView = new ObservableListView(); 
ObservableGridView gridView = new ObservableGridView();

Object obj;

if(condition)
{
    obj = listView;
}
else
{
    obj = gridView;
}

if(obj instanceof ObservableListView)
{
    ((ObservableListView)obj).someMethodOnlyInThisClass();
}
else if(obj instanceof ObservableGridView)
{
    ((ObservableGridView)obj).someOtherMethodOnlyInThisClass();
}
```

I would avoid using reflection.

Inheritance only works if the method you want to use is in both classes and inherited from a super class.

Interfaces work if the super class doesn't have the same method but both child classes do implement the interface.

`instanceof` is probably the most flexible solution that doesn't use reflection though some look down upon its use.

---

Since you updated your answer with a more clear objective. Here's what I would do.

```
AdapterView view = (AdapterView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.castdetailscredits);

if(view != null)
{
    view.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    ((Scrollable)view).setScrollViewCallbacks(activity.getCastDetailsFragment());
    ((Scrollable)view).setTouchInterceptionViewGroup((ViewGroup) activity.getCastDetailsFragment().getView().findViewById(R.id.containerLayout));
    Bundle save = activity.getCastDetailsCreditsBundle();

    if (save != null) {
        moviesList = save.getParcelableArrayList("moviesList");
        movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row, this.moviesList);
        view.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
    }
}
```

We use a couple of techniques here that I mentioned above. Specifically the *Inheritance* (`AdapterView`) and *Interface* (`Scrollable`).

Comment: Thank you for your time! I will try your solutions. And I will give feedback.

Comment: @RadoslavYordanov since you updated your question, i'm going to update my answer shortly with a good solution to your code duplication problem. Good job on looking for ways to avoid code duplication :)

Comment: Why would you avoid using reflection? I love reflection and find it to be super-useful when I build something along the lines of a configurable abstract factory pattern.  People _claim_ "poor performance" but I've never found it to be the bottleneck.

Comment: @StephenP I mostly suggest avoid using reflection because it's like using a shotgun when you only need a pistol. In your case, it's probably really awesome and I wouldn't advise against using it with something so abstract but in OP's case there are plenty of other solutions. Additionally, if you use reflection you don't get the safety of the compiler if you write something wrong; only runtime errors.

Comment: @iismathwizard cheers for your answer! Thanks a lot! This is the solution I have been looking for. Everything is working as expected.